Hebrew and lucifer
Here this Christian apologist mentions at 10:15 to 10:45 that hilal is related to the Hebrew word for lucifer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aGcRx-zu54 And mainly
https://www.ibnzura.com/answer.php?lang=en&id=55004&q=Qur’an_113:1:_moongod_according_to_Isaiah_14:12?
This post suggests that the quran claims god is "lord of the dawn" while the bible says Lucifer is "son of the dawn" is there any theological connection here. Another claim the site makes is that linguistically the word for lucifer is the similar to new moon or moon god in Hebrew again pushing for the moon god theory against islam. How accurate is this claim?

@curiousdannii - It appears to me that this question actually referenced a specific text, viz, Isa 14:12.  So, what is the problem here?

@Dottard It doesn't actually ask an exegetical question about it however, it's really focused on etymology, not the text. (I guess I did choose the wrong close reason.)

Lucifer is a Latin word for morning star, translated from the Greek φωσφόρος, and is seen in direct relation to Jesus Christ in 2 Peter 1:19 in the Latin Vulgate, translated day star in English in this instance, though the Latin clearly calls Jesus lucifer by way of epithet.

Et habemus firmiorem propheticum sermonem : cui benefacitis
attendentes quasi lucernae lucenti in caliginoso donec dies elucescat,
et lucifer oriatur in cordibus vestris.
We have also a more sure word of prophecy; whereunto ye do well that
ye take heed, as unto a light that shineth in a dark place, until the
day dawn, and the day star arise in your hearts.

The notion that "lucifer" refers to a fallen angel is from the overactive imagination of Origen in his De Principiis (On the First Principles). (Or. Princ. 1.5.5)
In truth, the passage, if its prophetic tone intends someone other than the king of Babylon as stated, actually has more in common with Christ than it does with Satan.
The morning star is fallen (14:12), and Jesus declares himself the bright and morning star (Rev. 22:16). This person is also referred to as the son of the morning (14:12), son in this case being a firstborn son, or heir of the morning. Jesus is called both the beginning and the "firstborn," or heir, of all creation (Col. 1:18). The person in the prophecy claimed that they would ascend above the clouds and be like the most high (14:13-14). Jesus said that he would be seated at the right hand of God (Matt. 26:64). But that person was brought down to hell and to the pit. Jesus was taken to Golgotha (known to be a pit/rock quarry), and descended into hell (Eph. 4:8-10). This person is said to have been cast out of the grave like an abominable branch (14:19). Jesus rose from the dead, and is recognized symbolically as the branch (Isa. 11:1; Jer. 23:5).
I would still personally agree with Dan Fefferman that this prophecy concerns the king of Babylon. Nevertheless, it is worth noting that the particulars have more in common with Jesus than with Satan if one is going to find significance in the prophecy beyond the king of Babylon to whom it is addressed.

You have to really cherry-pick to see Isaiah 14 as paralleling Jesus. Sure, Jesus is called the branch, but "abominable branch"? Verse 19 continues by comparing to "raiment of those that are slain" and "a carcase trodden under feet". This is pretty explicitly about a dishonorable burial, not a resurrection. Verse 20 refers to him as an evildoer. And Babylon is always associated with evil - see Revelation. Identifying Jesus with the king of Babylon seems blasphemous.

I didn’t say it refers to Jesus. I said it has more in common with things associated with him than with Satan. And I concluded with a direct statement that I believe it is a prophecy to the king of Babylon, to whom it is addressed. This prophecy in the strictest sense doesn’t rightly fit Jesus OR Satan. I was simply pointing out some of the similarities.

I did get that you're not actually saying the text refers to Jesus. The point is, if you're looking for a prophetic significance to the text, you have to really distort it to see a parallel with Christ (I think you agree). While you might find the arguments for seeing it as a reference to Satan unconvincing, they don't do the same violence to the text, which invalidates the argument in your last three paragraphs.

Honestly, given the mortal characteristics of the prophecy, I think the same violence is done to the text for either. Satan isn't going to die according to scripture. He wasn't thrown out of heaven until the advent of Christ. He was never in the grave to be tossed out. Very little of it fits the bill for the devil.

I'll note that many/most who see this text as prophetic would view it as having a double meaning, referring both literally to the literal king of Babylon and symbolically to Satan, thus explaining the mortal characteristics. This seems plausible to me (I'm honestly not convinced either way), because one way or another, there is symbolism in this passage. The king of Babylon didn't literally fall from heaven. Satan, on the other hand, literally did (incidentally, I don't see support for the claim that it happened only after the advent of Christ, but even if true I'm not sure it matters).

Zech. 3 and Rev. 12:10. Satan accused the brethren day and night before God. "Now is come salvation . . . and the power of his Christ: for the accuser of our brethren is cast down, which accused them before our God day and night."

As shown in the appendix below, the name "Lucifer" does not occur anywhere in the Hebrew.  It is a Latin word, the equivalent of the Hebrew הֵילֵל "helel" (Isa 14:12) both of which simply mean "bright" or "shining" - both were used for the name of Venus.
Further, the word for "moon" in Hebrew is יָרֵחַ (yareach) which is unrelated to הֵילֵל (helel) either linguistically or theologically.  The word is never used to describe any moon-god.  The assertions in the OP's link about "Lucifer" meaning "crescent moon" are without foundation - no evidence is offered at all.  It is simply false.
Lastly, the text of Qua'an at surah 113:1 says this (from the King Fahd version)

Say: "I seek refuge with (Allah), the Lord of the daybreak,

Again, this is unrelated to Isa 14:12.
APPENDIX - The Name "Lucifer"
It will come as a shock to some that the name “Lucifer” does not occur in the Hebrew Bible at all; it is in neither the Hebrew text nor the Greek text of the LXX.  It is an unfortunate translation of the KJV (and of John Wycliffe) in Isa 14:12 which most modern versions do not have.  What are the facts?

The Hebrew word in Isa 14:12 is הֵילֵל (helel - a hapex legamenon), meaning, “shining one”, from the root word, “halal” meaning, “to shine”.  The word was used to describe Venus, the morning (or evening) star (actually a planet!), but which easily outshines Sirius.  The complete phrase in the Hebrew is “helel ben-shachar” meaning “Venus, son of the morning”, or, “Morning star, son of the morning”.
The Septuagint (in Greek) translated the word, “heosphoros” which means, “Morning star”.  This translation is correct.
The Latin Vulgate (Jerome 400 AD) translated the word, “lucifer” meaning “light bearer”.  This translation is correct – for Latin.

It is apparent that the KJV translators struggled with the Hebrew and transliterated the Latin word instead of translating it.  John Wycliffe (who translated from the Latin and knew no Greek or Hebrew) also appears to have been flummoxed as he left the word untranslated.  They appear to ignore the fact that the same word appears elsewhere in the Latin Bible describing other things.  (2 Peter 1:19, Job 11:17, 38:32, Ps 110:3)
It is only in the later English Christian tradition that “Lucifer” became a proper noun referring to the Devil before his fall, which the Hebrew does not do.
Note the comments of Ellicott on Isa 14:12 -

(12) How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the
morning!—The word for Lucifer is, literally, the shining one, the
planet Venus, the morning star, the son of the dawn, as the symbol of
the Babylonian power, which was so closely identified with astrolatry.
“Lucifer” etymologically gives the same meaning, and is used by Latin
poets (Tibull. i., 10, 62) for Venus, as an equivalent for the
phôsphoros of the Greeks.

See also Barnes and Benson in this location:  https://biblehub.com/commentaries/isaiah/14-12.htm
What does Isa 14;12 refer to?
Isa 14 is part of a larger passage, Isa 13:1 - Isa 14:27 - a prophecy about the king of Babylon.  This much is not controversial.
However, many Christians have understood a few verses (Isa 14:12-15) in this prophecy about the king of Babylon as describing the origin and fall of Satan.  That is, such people interpret Isa 14:12-15 about the king of Babylon with a secondary meaning as applying to Satan.  For example, see the commentary by Ellicott
This is disputed by some and its not the subject of this question to debate or even discuss these understandings here; in any case, that discussion would venture into theology.  I will simply quote Ellicott's further comment on Isa 14:12 about the origin of the name "Lucifer" as a proper name in English:

The use of the word [Lucifer], however, in mediæval Latin as a name of
Satan, whose fall was supposed to be shadowed forth in this and the
following verse, makes its selection here singularly unfortunate. Few
English readers realise the fact that it is the king of Babylon, and
not the devil, who is addressed as Lucifer. While this has been the
history of the Latin word, its Greek and English equivalents have
risen to a higher place, and the “morning star” has become a name of
the Christ (Revelation 22:16).

Finally, as if to summarize the situation, let me quote the comments of Albert Barnes in Isa 14;12 about "Lucifer".

How art thou fallen from heaven - A new image is presented here. It is
that of the bright morning star; and a comparison of the once
magnificent monarch with that beautiful star. He is now exhibited as
having fallen from his place in the east to the earth. His glory is
dimmed; his brightness quenched. Nothing can be more poetic and
beautiful than a comparison of a magnificent monarch with the bright
morning star! Nothing more striking in representing his death, than
the idea of that star falling to the earth! Lucifer - Margin,
'Day-star' (הילל hēylēl, from הלל hâlal, "to shine"). The word in
Hebrew occurs as a noun nowhere else. In two other places Ezekiel
21:12; Zechariah 11:2, it is used as a verb in the imperative mood of
Hiphil, and is translated 'howl' from the verb ילל yālal, "to howl"
or "cry." Gesenius and Rosenmuller suppose that it should be so
rendered here. So Noyes renders it, 'Howl, son of the morning!' But
the common translation seems to be preferable. The Septuagint renders
it, Ἑωσφόρος Heōsphoros, and the Vulgate, 'Lucifer, the morning
star.' The Chaldee, 'How art thou fallen from high, who wert splendid
among the sons of men.' There can be no doubt that the object in the
eve of the prophet was the bright morning star; and his design was to
compare this magnificent oriental monarch with that. The comparison of
a monarch with the sun, or the other heavenly bodies, is common in the
Scriptures.
Son of the morning - This is a Hebraism (see the note at Matthew 1:1),
and signifies that that bright star is, as it were, the production, or
the offspring of morning; or that it belongs to the morning. The word
'son' often thus denotes possession, or that one thing belongs to
another. The same star in one place represents the Son of God himself;
Revelation 21:16 [sic; should be 22:16] : 'I am - the bright and morning star.'


""In Semitic languages חַרשׂ means “moongod”, "" so this has no basis? , i think the op was trying to make a connection with helel( whichever language this is) to hilal in arabic , which means crescent moon , i asdumed this meant moon in Hebrew too

There is no Hebrew word for Lucifer.  In Isaiah 14:21 the term "Helal ben Shaḥar" means "the brilliant one, son of the morning". In the Septuagint, this became Φωσφόρος (phosophoros) and is translated into English via Latin as Lucifer. Neither the OT nor the NT actually mentions 'Lucifer' or  its Greek and Hebrew equivalents as the name of an archangel.
So strictly speaking the Bible does not say that the archangel Lucifer is "son of the dawn." Rather "son of the dawn" (ben Shahar) is an epithet describing "Helal."  The passage in Isaiah 14 addresses the historical the King of Babylon, predicting his utter degradation.

4 you will take up this taunt-song against the king of Babylon - How
the oppressor has come to an end!
how the turmoil has ended!... 9 Below, Sheol is all astir
preparing for your coming; Awakening the shades to greet you...
you are just like us! 11 Down to Sheol your pomp is brought,
the sound of your harps. Maggots are the couch beneath you,
worms your blanket 12 How you have fallen from the heavens,
O Morning Star, son of the dawn!

Conclusion: The idea that Isaiah 14 is speaking about the archangel Lucifer is a product of later theology. The Bible itself uses the term "Helal ben Shaḥar" to refer to the King of Babylon, a man who would die like any other man. This does not mean that either Christian or Islamic theologians are mistaken, only that the Bible itself does not speak of an archangel by the name in question.
